# python sqlite3 i have a database how to take prim key input and then take value of anther key in database

Tags: python, sqlite

example

```
conn= sqlite3.connect("test.db")
```

```
 ID           INT  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
 SEX           TEXT  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
```

after inserting the data example

```
1 male
2 male
3 male
4 male
5 female
6 male
7 male
```

I want the user(input) write the id then I print the SEX from database if ID valid

```
print("what id you want his sex")
x=input()#4 example
```

I want the sqlite code to take x(id) and from x he give me the sex(male)-

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a few issues with 1. What you are trying to do, and 2. how you are trying to do it.

First thing to note, is that you cannot have multiple Primary Keys (PK) in 1 SQL table.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the below statement:

```
conn= sqlite3.connect("test.db") ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, SEX TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
```

`conn=sqlite3.connect("test.db")` is used to connect to a database that already exists called test.db, if it does not exist it will create it.

If you are trying to create a new table with the cols you have provided, this could be done by:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("test.db")

c = conn.cursor()

c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXIST users(
             ID int PRIMARY_KEY NOT NULL,
             sex text)'''
conn.commit()
```

Once the table is initialised, if you are trying to insert:

```
c.execute('''INSERT INTO users (id, Sex)
             SELECT
             1,
             'male''''
conn.commit()
```

Now, if you are trying to access that data, you can:

```
c.execute('''SELECT sex FROM users WHERE ID = 1'''
result = [dict(row) for row in c.fetchall()]
print(result)
```

Again, from your question it is very unclear what you are trying to do... but I thought i'd put some SQLITE3 basics down anyway.

EDIT based on clarification in comments:

The below script is an example of how you could create a database, create a table in that database, and then insert some dummy data - the function `get_user_by_id` executes the sql select statement. This function is then called in main where it uses the id input by the user as the parameter in the query:

```
import sqlite3

# Connect to db
conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
c = conn.cursor()
# Create table for storing data
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
                ID INT PRIMARY_KEY NOT NULL,
                sex text)''')
# commit the changes to the database
conn.commit()
# inserting dummy data
c.execute('''INSERT INTO users (ID, sex)
            SELECT
            1,
            "male"''')
conn.commit()

def get_user_by_id(id):
    # conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
    # c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT sex FROM users WHERE id = ?", (id,))
    result = c.fetchone()
    return result

def main():
    id = int(input("Enter User ID: "))
    sex = get_user_by_id(id)

    print(sex[0])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Just a note to the poster - please in future try to be clear and concise in your questions to help us help you.

Comment: the question is here with your last code                                        c.execute('''SELECT sex FROM users WHERE ID = (input)'''
result = [dict(row) for row in c.fetchall()]
#print(result) how to take 1 as a user input

Comment: hi @Khalid - i've updated my answer with an example of how it can be done. Please dont forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied :)